Nestjs: How to import a dynamic module multiple times
I've created a dynamic module to use for different queues, receiving the endpoint in the .forRoot():
@Module({
  imports: [],
  controllers: [],
  providers: [
    QueuesService,
    QueuesRepository,
    { provide: 'SQSClient', useValue: defaultRepository },
    { provide: 'QueueEndpoint', useValue: '' }
  ],
  exports: [QueuesService]
})
export class QueuesModule {
  static forRoot(options: { endpoint: string }): DynamicModule {
    const providers = [
      QueuesService,
      QueuesRepository,
      { provide: 'SQSClient', useValue: defaultRepository },
      { provide: 'QueueEndpoint', useValue: options.endpoint }
    ]
    return {
      module: QueuesModule,
      providers: providers,
      exports: [QueuesService]
    }
  }
}

I am then importing it in other services like this, and so far it is working fine:
imports: [QueuesModule.forRoot({ endpoint: 'http://foo.queue/' })],

And injecting like that:
constructor(
  private readonly fooQueueService: QueuesService
) {}

This has been working fine. But now I have a module that uses more than 1 queue at the same time, and i'm not sure how to approach it.
I thought of two possibilities:

Importing the module twice while, somehow, setting a key for the different services:

constructor(
  @Inject('FooQueueService') private readonly fooQueueService: QueuesService,
  @Inject('BarQueueService') private readonly barQueueService: QueuesService,
) {}

The problem with that is i'm not sure how to import the same module twice and set the different keys in the module, and i couldn't find anything in the nestjs docs. I know how to provide keys inside the module, but i'm not sure how would i provide the service from an imported module like that and how would i import it multiple times.

Exporting all queues from queues module
Today I have around ~10 different queues, I could inject the queue endpoint into QueuesService instead of QueuesRepository and then export all my different queues in QueuesService. I'm not a big fan of this solution, but i guess it would work out. Something like that (Just a code to express my idea):

const fooQueueservice = new QueuesService('http://foo.queue/') //also not sure how i would receive this param in the constructor but at the same time inject QueuesRepository
const barQueueservice = new QueuesService('http://bar.queue/') 
const bazQueueservice = new QueuesService('http://baz.queue/') 

[...]

exports: [
  {provide: 'fooQueue', useValue: fooQueueService},
  {provide: 'barQueue', useValue: barQueueservice},
  {provide: 'bazQueue', useValue: bazQueueService}
]


Exporting the imported module
I think this would be the ideal solution for me. All queues have a module for it, so if i could just "re-export" i could then import it from the specific module, something like that:

@Module({
  providers: [FooService],
  imports: [QueuesModule.forRoot({ endpoint: 'http://foo.queue/' })],
  exports: [FooService, { provide: 'FooQueueService', useExisting: QueuesService }] //something like that
})
export class FooModule {}

Anyways, i'm not sure how to approach this problem and couldn't find any solution anywhere, any help would be welcome.
